# Is it an homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a set and let $h:2^M\rightarrow 2^M$ defined by $h(A)=\overline{A}$, for all $A\in 2^M$.

How can we check if $h$ is an homomorphism from $(2^M, \cup)$ to $(2^M, \cup)$ ?

Do we have to check if $h$ is monomorphism, epimorphism and isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, if it is a monomorphism and a epimorphism then it is an isomorphism.

Generally, a homomorphism is a map that preserves structure between algebraic structures. To check if a map is a homomorphism from $(S_1,\cdot_1)$ to $(S_2,\cdot_2)$ you should also check that

$$f(a \cdot_1 b) = f(a)\cdot_2f(b) \text{ for all } a,b \in S_1$$

Comment: So, in this case we have to check if $$h(A_1 \cup A_2)=h(A_1)\cup h(A_2), \ A_1, A_2\in 2^M$$ right? 
$$$$ 
We have that $$h(A_1\cup A_2)=\overline{A_1\cup A_2}$$ What exactly means $\overline{A}$ ? Is this the closure of the set $A$ ?

Comment: The closure of the union of two sets is equal to the union of two closures of sets, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to check. As to the notation, I would just be assuming. If it is indeed closure, then that is what you must show.

Comment: How do we show that the closure of the union of two sets is equal to the union of two closures of sets?